Best way to deduplicate a database which has name, email, address, DOB, phone number and a few binary flags?
I have a database which has duplicate records (same customer creating multiple accounts). Their unique identifier column value is different for each NameID, but other information might be same.
For example, there is a person named Mark. He created two guest users:
Guest User 1:
Name ID= 12345
Name = Mark Thomas
IsOnlineshopper = 1
Isinstoreshopper = 0
DOB = 01/12/1998
Email = mark.thomas@hotmail.com
Address = # 12 Bailey Street, New Jersey, USA
Phone =03248923423

Guest User 2:
Name ID= 56789
Name = Mark Thomas
IsOnlineshopper = 0
Isinstoreshopper = 1
DOB = 01/12/1998
Email = mark.thomas@hotmail.com
Address = # 12 Bailey Street, New Jersey, USA
Phone =03248923423

Now this is one of the scenarios where 'IsOnlineshopper' and 'Isinstoreshopper 'are different, but all other parameters are same. There can be scenarios where the person might enter a wrong phone number and all the other parameters are same. There are many scenarios, but I want to start with the simplest one where all fields are matching.
My goal is to achieve:
NameIDs with a 100 % match and list them as duplicates (link all matched to each other by a common ID) based on following algo:

if name matches a 100% go next step, else not a match.
if email matches a 100% go next step, else not a match.
if phone number matches a 100% go next step, else not a match.
if address matches a 100% go next step, else not a match.
if address DOB a 100% go next step, else not a match.
based on following priority mark as primary and duplicate



NameID having IsOnlineshopper should be marked as primary.
NameID having Isinstoreshopper should be marked as duplicate.


After matching and merging these names once (clear up the system), I want to automate the process but running the process each day where all the incoming records (duplicates) are merged with the primary names.
I have data in Azure SQL, and I have options to use Databricks (considering data is huge and might take more computational power). I have created a subset of the main dataset to test. But I am not sure what approach should I use to do deduplication.
I researched a bit and looks like Machine learning can be used in this case. I am also thinking of hardcoding this in pyspark. But as I mentioned I am not sure which way is the best to go.
Please share your thoughts. Thank you.
